# Google Maps autocomplete with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I want the following:

- Page 1: An search field. The user can type in his address in it will autocomplete. After submitting the address, we're going on with page 2
- Page 2: The user can see Google Maps, centered to his entered address

How can I realize page 1? I've found autocomplete for Google Maps Places, but I want it for the address.

**Edit:
Thats my script of page 1, but how can I pass the entered address to the next page and redirect to the next page?**

```
<div data-role="content">
    <label for="searchAddress">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" id="searchAddress" name="searchAddress" />
    <input type="button" id="addAddress" value="Search"/>
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById('searchAddress');
    var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Consider doing it on the same page. 2. The places autocomplete is for Google to suggest places AS YOU TYPE in an input field. This is where I don't get your idea of "pass the address to the next page"

Answer (score 0):

// Set on page 1 submit

```
localStorage.setItem('searchAddress', $('#searchAddress').val());
```

// On page 2

```
var input = localStorage.getItem('searchAddress');
var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```